# Change background image of a button (button is in super class) in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have inherited my custom class in my project.i.e instead of using the UIViewController i have inherited my custom class.That custom class is having the button.When I am in firstViewController i have to change the background image of that button.for that I have written

```
 [super.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

But it is not changing the background image.

Kindly help me .I have stuccoed here.If it is done then my project will be completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"super" calls a class, not an instance, you probably want to call an instance.

if button is a property defined in your superclass and you are in a subclass, then you can directly access to that property, as if it was defined in the subclass, so just try:

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I have tried this.But it is not changing the background image.kindly help me

Comment: try log self.button... we cannot find where the problem is with just that code, but just "guess": is self.button == nil?  try NSLog(@"%@",self.button);  what's the report?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of direct assigning image name to `setBackgroundImage`...try this one...

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"]];
[self.button setBackgroundImage:imgView];
```

This will perfectly fruitful to you....:)

Comment: It is not changing the background image dude help me please

Comment: @pie: Ok...But IT WAS PERFECTLY WORKING FOR ME IN PAST.....I think you have to check syntactically for your problem...remove 'self' attached with 'button'.This may not be solution...and check whether your imagename is proper..whether you have properly delegated button, drag the button or not....try these all.....:)

Comment: @pie: Have you found the solution??